# Why are immediatly invoked functions in event handles invoked before triggering the event?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let a = (function gigel() {
    alert("dd");
})();
```

```html
* this is executed immediatly as the page loads*
    <button onclick="a">Click me</button>

* this is executed only when clicking the button *
    <button onclick="alert('dd')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking so that your answer would be more likely to be answered than downvoted.

Comment: An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the event by `(function gigel...)()` and as the invocation returns nothing `a` would not be a function. Also `a` isn't being called, you would want to the following:

```js
let a = (function gigel() {
  alert("IIFE");
});
```

```html
* this is executed immediately as the page loads*
<button onclick="a()">Click me</button> 
* this is executed only when clicking the button *
<button onclick="alert('dd')">Click me</button>
```

Or if you want to invoke it immediately and store it in `a`:

```js
let a = (function gigel() {
  alert("IIFE");
  return gigel;
})();
```

```html
* this is executed immediately as the page loads*
<button onclick="a()">Click me</button> 
* this is executed only when clicking the button *
<button onclick="alert('dd')">Click me</button>
```